# typescript: allow merge types, include all from first type and include all from second or none

Tags: typescript, types, union

I want to create a type based on `BaseProps` and `ExtraProps`.
All the `ExtraProps`' properties should exist or not, so if I add one of them, I should add all other `ExtraProps`' properties

```
type BaseProps = {
  prop1: string;
  prop2: number;
};

type ExtraProps = {
  extraPropA: boolean;
  extraPropB: string;
};

type MyType = BaseProps | (BaseProps & ExtraProps);
```

Usage:

```
const obj1: MyType = {
  prop1: "value1",
  prop2: 42,
  extraPropB: "someValue" // should fail (no extraPropA)
};

const obj2: MyType = {
  prop1: "value2",
  prop2: 55,
  extraPropA: true // // should fail (no extraPropB)
};

const obj3: MyType = {
  prop1: "value3",
  prop2: 12 // OK, only BaseProps is present
};

const obj4: MyType = {
  prop1: "value4",
  prop2: 555,
  extraPropA: true,
  extraPropB: "someValue" // OK, both extra props are present
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgZwgBQE4HswKgXigbwCgoowMwBGALigWFQEsA7AcwG5jTyAmGpgVwC2AIwioOAXw6FQkKAFEAHvThpM2PERIRlqVeQCCNYenQAbCHCYdtu-Zhg06jVpOmzoAWRAAVcNDx4JDUsKAAfKAAKIJRybAAyBTsQhABKaQB6DKS4QTALKH4EOBYIKkIAY3QmOih0YQAraihvPzlNTjJMZoAiADc4M34ICh6AGk6eGgAWbgnbFRDHKB6EdEEIADVB4Z6oLNoAC3R%20MwATKAAzOAYzKKZ0KB1Fw1TCKUJK6tr6ht4W3z%20XAESbdGj9HYQbjjUFgf4AVnh8yeyUMNHow322QOCGOpwu11u90ezz0SzeHy%20NWAdUaAGYaK0gR0SF1KOCBkMIHSYayplAKNwsVAAPIAaTGdSYZhAsEQsXUUAY2DIECQTGA72kVWptIa00ZgPaIL5YJWnOG015XEwCMRyNJ9jARigGIgDtRDnBaw22y5ewO4slJmAhxRKhtoTgqGgqvVmspJCAA)

Comment: I'm sure I've seen a previous question on this, I'll try to find it. The problem is that those are valid objects of type `BaseProps` (because objects can have extra properties), and excess property checks on object literals don't apply when there's a union.

Comment: Yup, found it. The solution is to add the properties as optional with type never on the left hand of the union, [like this](https://tsplay.dev/Na5M6N).

Comment: (Off-topic, but: This is a great example of a well-asked question! Had all the detail, all the types, a playground link, and a clear statement of what should work and what should error. Nice one!)